# Component module not found - Storybook - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webpack, runtime-error, node-modules, storybook

When I run Storybook, I'm getting the following error:

```bash
ERROR in ./components/atoms/input/input.tsx 14:0-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-tagsinput' in '...'
```

To give context of my environment, here's my setup:

**Directory**

```
root
|.storybook
  |-main.ts
|-components
  |-atoms
    |-input
      |-input.tsx
      |-input.stories.ts
|-node_modules
```

**main.ts**

```js
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/nextjs";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../components/**/*.mdx", "../components/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/nextjs",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  }
};
export default config;
```

**input.stories.ts**

```js
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
import Input from './input';

// Rest of code here...
```

**input.tsx**

```js
import React, { InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import TagsInput from 'react-tagsinput';

// Rest of code here...
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-tagsinput": "^3.20.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.1",
    "next": "14.0.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "swr": "^2.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.15",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "storybook": "^7.5.3",
    "style-dictionary": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

I've tried following some of the recommendations found within Storybook's website (https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack#typescript-module-resolution), but with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, installing both `@types/react-tagsinput` and `react-tagsinput` allows me to use the module when running just Storybook or NextJS. `@types/react-tagsinput` was needed to use it within the input component written in TypeScript. Although this works, I don't believe this is the best solution. I'm sure there is a configuration to resolve this properly, I'm just not fully understanding how.